# HPA on AWS EKS with Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, hpa

I have AWS EKS cluster with only Fargate profile, no Node Groups.
Is it possible to enable HPA in this case? I tried to enable metric server as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/metrics-server.html) but pod creation fails with error

```
0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) had taint {eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type: fargate}, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Any insights?

Comment: HPA should work fine with EKS/Fargate. I haven't tested it recently but I remember having gone through [this mini-tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html) and it worked fine. Can you start a pod on Fargate (outside of the context of HPA)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create fargate profile for this.
If you are deploying it into another namespace then you need to create a fargate profile for that namespace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your node have a taint - for which there is no corresponding tolerations added to pod/deployment specs. You can find more about [taints and tolerations here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#concepts)

About autoscaling of pods it is indeed possible as can be seen from similar tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/autoscaling-eks-on-fargate-with-custom-metrics/)